# Postfix Is it possible to rewrite From: field to email used in authorization procedure

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

It's known that users can provide any email in From: field.
I need to prevent it by rewriting it to email used in authorization procedure.
Is it possible to do in postfix? Or may be other MTA?

Answer (score 3):

Yes [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) to include [`reject_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) or [`reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch) along with any other restrictions you put in place (order does matter).

The table doesn't have to be `hash` and probably shouldn't be. If your setup is rather simple you will want [`PCRE`](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html) or [`regex`](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html). More complicated setups use [`ldap`](http://www.postfix.org/ldap_table.5.html), [`mysql`](http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html),[`PostgreSQL`](http://www.postfix.org/pgsql_table.5.html) or [`SQLite`](http://www.postfix.org/sqlite_table.5.html).

You can also mix and match, but do so with caution and proper testing [`postmap -q`](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html).

Depending how your clients are setup you may need to set [`smtpd_sasl_local_domain`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_local_domain).

Additional examples: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_sasl_authz

Comment: Yes, it is better do REJECT a bad sender instead of rewriting it to a good one.